# How to fire an application event from the browser developer console

Tags: lightning

I'm trying to get some debug information from my application, but setting breakpoints in my code is very time consuming.

I registered an application event named "debug" and added a handler in my component that will spit out some debug information (using `console.log`). I set the access control to "global":

**debug.evt**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" access="global" />
```

I was hoping that I could just create and fire the event from the javascript developer console:

```
> $A.get('e.namespace:debug')
```

... but that just returned `undefined`. I'm still new to developing in Lightning and I'm beginning to question whether this is even possible.

Comment: I think I've got all the relevant information in my question, but if there's something I'm missing just let me know in the comments and I'll update as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Oops...

Looks like it was as easy as I had hoped after all, I just hadn't actually added the handler to my component yet. As soon as I added the handler, the event was recognized and I was able to create it from the console.

For posterity, here's the handler XML I added to my component (which must actually be loaded on the screen for this to work):

```
<aura:handler event="c:debug" action="{!c.handleDebug}"/>
```